# Triggering a URL on startup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, toolbar

I recently came across a problem in my google chrome where on its startup the URL-  http://www.search.ask.com/ automatically triggers ?
This is ***not similar to ask.com problem*** because i tried all these:

1. finding extension in chrome for ask.com - N/A (not available)
2. internet options -> home page -> is blank ..
3. removing unnecessary URL's from chrome target properties.
4. Using Ccleaner to search for chrome startup applications etc.
5. Obviously the default search engine is not set to ask.com

Then why this problem? Where is this URL coming on every time i start or click my chrome icon.? Moreover i Want to know:

1. How can i make a script that if anyone visits my website then his default home page is my websites URL
2. How can i add my URL in the chrome properties TARGET ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, kept popping up when Chrome was first run even after changing the homepage. Try this, there's a separate section in the settings for your start up page. I'd missed it about half a dozen times until I found this help page.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95421?hl=en-GB